# Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet Driver VLAN support

Tags: vlan, drivers

I am using Atheros L1 Gigabit Ethernet Driver on 60 desktop machines and these machines I need to have on VLAN 2 for which I need to create VLAN 2 on all these desktops but the driver does not shows options for creating VLANS.

How can I do it????

Help....

Comment: You would typically configure your VLAN's on your switch.

Comment: I need to enable VLAN 2 Tagging of frames from each desktop machine, so the frames going out of the network interface will by default be tagged as VLAN 2.